# A permission issue with deploy an iOS app use travis ci

Tags: ios, travis-ci

1. .travis.yml is validated
2. Travis CI is build succeeded.
3. Xcode 7.1.1, Mac OSX El Capitan 10.11 Beta

fir:http://fir.im

Do these progress from : https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/travis-ci/#encrypt-certificates-and-profiles

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
Then I try to deploy to fir,I received from Travis CI:

```
/Users/travis/build.sh: line 41: ./scripts/sign-and-upload.sh: Permission denied
```

I thought the file "sign-and-upload.sh" isn't been permission. So I give these files appropriate permissions:

```
before_install:
- chmod +x scripts/add-key.sh
- chmod +x scripts/remove-key.sh
```

But it still failed.

This is the add-key.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
security create-keychain -p travis ios-build.keychain
security default-keychain -s ios-build.keychain
security unlock-keychain -p travis ios-build.keychain
security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -l ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain

security import ./scripts/certs/apple.cer -k ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain -T /usr/bin/codesign
security import ./scripts/certs/dist.cer -k ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain -T /usr/bin/codesign
security import ./scripts/certs/dist.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/ios-build.keychain -P 123 -T /usr/bin/codesign
mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
cp ./scripts/profile/$PROFILE_NAME.mobileprovision ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that `sign-and-upload.sh` needs execute permission.  But your response was to change some different files!  You need to add

```
- chmod +x scripts/sign-and-upload.sh
```